# How to load the previous URL in HTML when creating a website using HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser

I have edited a website template that contains HTML files. However, when I click the back button in any browser, I get a blank white page. I see the previous URL in the browser, but it doesn't fully load until I press F5. What specific code can I add to my HTML that will load the previous page? Would I add this code to each HTML file? As I am new to HTML, a very specific answer would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What website template are you using? Include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For example: my contact page looks like this: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>M | Monika</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='Be is a responsive HTML5 Template suitable for any kind of business or freelance professional. Showcase your work, tell your story, get noticed online.' name='description'>
    <meta content='1 day' name='revisit-after'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>
  and I am using this portfolio: https://elements.envato.com/be-portfolio-template-for-creatives-7JV5FP

Comment: You need to provide the code necessary to reproduce what your talking about, the code you've provided is just what's in the head tag, doesn't show what the problem is... Please include the code in the editing box not in these comments

Comment: @JorgeZ I am not sure where this code is located in the HTML files I am working with. I have been searching for "back" and "History" without success.